# How can I open a page in new window using javascript or typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to open a page in new window. I have written the following code

```
  navigateToURL() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");
  }
```

But it opens in a new tab whereas I need to open in a new window. Can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open3) link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following-

```
navigateToURL() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
}
```

Comment: it still opens in a new tab

Comment: I've tested with google chrome and opera. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this?

```
<body>
<button 
     onclick="Navigate2URL()">Open 
      Google</button>

   <script>
   function Navigate2URL(){

 window.open("https://www.google.com","yourName","height=200,width=200");
    }
  </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: It will also open the new tab..

Comment: It will open in new tab. I want to open in new window.

Comment: Ok i have edited it